# Building Real World AngularJS apps, how should I declare my controllers in html. Do I need to declare all in the index.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, design-patterns, architecture

I have an application based on e.g. the Northwind database, in which I have built views for each of the different objects to maintain them CRUD-ly, using AngularJS views and the in typical file structure adopted by most devs.

I have an issue I would like to improve, firstly from all examples I have seen, you need to declare your controller on an index.html file. If one module that a user uses does not require, all the other controllers, is it necessary to load all controllers on the client side. Is there a better way to only declare controllers that are need per view?

Is this the normal behaivor of a Single Page LOB, to preload all necessary dependencies, whether required or not?

Comment: Your question is more of a philosophical than a practical one, it depends on your target audience for the app and if your app will be heavy or not and if you mind to take 1 second or 2 to load under what connection speed. There are lots of different examples of lazy loading. I would recommend checking out https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: might be of interest to you https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Don't declare your controllers in your HTML.
The less logic you add in your template, the more flexible your app will be.
The problem with including `controllers` in your HTML is that if some nested controllers have the same instance var (example foobar), then you don't know which one would be displayed :

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
...
   <div ng-controller="secondController">
   ...
   {foobar}
```

Then, the best way is to work with modules and routes. With routes, you can tell AngularJS that your HTML should be controlled by `aController`.
I you are looking for a good app to start with, take a look [at this one](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/tree/master/app).
It has been developped by the AnguarJS team and shows some good practices to follow. You can notice that none of the HTML files contain a reference to a controller.